# How to send values from Unity& receive in Java for my plugin?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I wants to send data from Unity to java for my android plugin.

**Here's my Unity Code:**

```
AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
IntPtr cls_Activity = AndroidJNI.FindClass("com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer");
    IntPtr fid_Activity = AndroidJNI.GetStaticFieldID(cls_Activity, "currentActivity", "Landroid/app/Activity;");
    IntPtr obj_Activity = AndroidJNI.GetStaticObjectField(cls_Activity, fid_Activity);                  
    Debug.Log("Setup Objects Complete");        

    IntPtr cls_OurAppNameActivityClass = AndroidJNI.FindClass("org/plugin/test/AdmobTestActivity"); 

    IntPtr startAdsMethod = AndroidJNI.GetMethodID(cls_OurAppNameActivityClass, "EnableAds", "(J)V");
    Debug.Log("before If Loop");        

    if (AndroidJNI.IsInstanceOf(obj_Activity, cls_OurAppNameActivityClass) != false)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Activity IS a OurAppNameActivity");
        jvalue[] myArray = new jvalue[1];
            myArray[0] = new jvalue();
            myArray[0].i = 12;
            AndroidJNI.CallVoidMethod(obj_Activity, startAdsMethod, myArray);                    

            Debug.Log("Activity Leaving a OurAppNameActivity");
    }
```

**Here's My Java Code:**

```
public void EnableAds(int qwe)
{       
    Log.i(APP_TAG, "Value" + qwe);
}
```

**ERRORS:**

```
05-16 13:11:30.906: W/dalvikvm(12315): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
05-16 13:11:30.921: E/AndroidRuntime(12315): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9
05-16 13:11:30.921: E/AndroidRuntime(12315): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: EnableAds
05-16 13:11:30.921: E/AndroidRuntime(12315):    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
05-16 13:11:30.921: E/AndroidRuntime(12315):    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source)
05-16 13:11:30.921: E/AndroidRuntime(12315):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1368)
05-16 13:11:30.921: E/AndroidRuntime(12315):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1123)
```

**AND FORCE CLOSE..**

This Applications is working fine if i removed int argument from EnableAdv(int qwe) in my java code..

Can anyone tell me, what thing i m missing in this code.?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Comment: **I found the answer..**
I want using "(J)V" as my argument type.. but instead of this i shud to use "(I)V".

**For example,** the Java method:

    long f (int n, String s, int[] arr); 

has the following type signature:

    "(ILjava/lang/String;[I)V"

Comment: Please post your finding as an answer and accept it a few hours later. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the answer..**

I want using "(J)V" as my argument type.. but instead of this i shud to use "(I)V".

**For example, the Java method:**

long f (int n, String s, int[] arr); 
has the following type signature:

"(ILjava/lang/String;[I)V

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp276) for further reading